# Mistake in Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

```
SELECT Student.S_ID, Student.First_Name, Student.Surname, 
       MAX(New_Models.Date_Issued) AS Last_Course_Date, 
       MAX(New_Models.Issue) AS Last_Issue, 
       MAX(New_Models.Model_ID) AS Last_Model_ID,
       Student.Course_Level AS No_Training_Courses,
       **COUNT(Exam_Student.Exam_ID) AS Final_Exam_Level**
FROM New_Models, Model_Student, Student, Exams, Exam_Student
WHERE New_Models.Model_ID=Model_Student.Model_ID 
  AND Student.S_ID=Model_Student.S_ID
  AND (Student.S_ID)=Exam_Student.S_ID
  AND ((Exams.Exam_ID)=Exam_Student.Exam_ID)
  AND (Exams.Date_Taken)<=#12/31/2010#
GROUP BY Student.S_ID, First_Name, Surname, S.Course_Level
ORDER BY Student.S_ID, MAX(New_Models.Model_ID) DESC;
```

All the result appear as required except the COUNT command. When comparing with actual result whihc should come only the first cell differs and is wrong.
It should be counting how many exams has the student done.

I can answer any questions, will be waiting for your help.

```
SELECT 
    Student.S_ID, 
    Student.first_name, 
    Student.surname, 
    MAX(new_models.date_issued) AS last_course_date, 
    MAX(new_models.issue) AS last_issue, 
    MAX(new_models.model_id) AS last_model_id, 
    Student.course_level AS no_training_courses 
FROM 
    new_models, 
    Student, 
    Model_Student 
WHERE 
    new_models.model_id = Model_Student.model_id 
    AND Student.S_id = Model_Student.S_id 
    AND *strong text*Exam_ID IN ( 
            SELECT COUNT(Exam_Student.Exam_id) AS Final_Exam_Level 
            FROM 
                Exams, 
                Exam_Student, 
                Student 
            WHERE 
                Student.S_ID = Exam_Student.S_ID 
                AND exams.date_taken <=#12/31/2010# 
            Group by Student.S_ID) 
GROUP BY 
    Student.S_ID,
    first_name, 
    surname, 
    Student.Course_level 
ORDER BY 
    Student.S_id, 
    MAX(new_models.model_id) DESC;
```

I cannot use INNER JOIN so, I was wondering that something like the above can be done. However, I dont know how to do the subquery!

Comment: So why exactly can't you use INNER JOINs?

Answer (score 3):

One approach that may help is to simply create a subquery on the Counts and then join to that.

I also recommend using ANSI-92 style joins

```
SELECT student.s_id, 
       student.first_name, 
       student.surname, 
       MAX(new_models.date_issued) AS last_course_date, 
       MAX(new_models.issue)       AS last_issue, 
       MAX(new_models.model_id)    AS last_model_id, 
       student.course_level        AS no_training_courses,
       Examqry.ExamCount 
FROM   new_models 
       INNER JOIN model_student ON  new_models.model_id = model_student.model_id 
       INNER JOIN student ON student.s_id = model_student.s_id 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(Exam_id) ExamCount , 
                                         s_id 
                           FROM exams Group by s_id
                          Where exams.date_taken <=#12/31/2010#) examqry
       ON student.s_id = examqry.s_id

GROUP  BY student.s_id, 
          first_name, 
          surname, 
          s.course_level 
ORDER  BY student.s_id, 
          MAX(new_models.model_id) DESC;
```

Comment: Where did u get examcount.examcount in SELECT from?

Comment: @qartrelana it came from the query in the from also called an inline view. I updated my answer to make it a little clearer. Examqry is the alias for the inline view. Exam count is the alias for the count of exam_id. Also my where was in the wrong place

Comment: I tried using your approach except that i cannot use inner join. But, the way I did it is not working now Can u plz check? SELECT Student.S_ID, Student.first_name, Student.surname, MAX(new_models.date_issued) AS last_course_date, MAX(new_models.issue) AS last_issue, MAX(new_models.model_id) AS last_model_id,

Comment: Student.course_level AS no_training_courses
FROM   new_models, Student, Model_Student
WHERE new_models.model_id = Model_Student.model_id
AND Student.S_id = Model_Student.S_id
AND Exam_ID IN (SELECT COUNT(Exam_Student.Exam_id) AS Final_Exam_Level
FROM Exams, Exam_Student, Student
Where Student.S_ID = Exam_Student.S_ID
AND exams.date_taken <=#12/31/2010#
Group by Student.S_ID)
GROUP  BY Student.S_ID,first_name, surname, Student.Course_level
ORDER  BY Student.S_id, MAX(new_models.model_id) DESC;

Comment: I put it in two posts, Can u figure that out? Thank you

Comment: @Qatrelnada just so you know, you're much better off editing your original question. that way everyone sees it as an active question rather than just me, and the community is almost always more responsive than just one person. That said it doesn't look right. `...exam_id IN (SELECT COUNT(exam_student.exam_id) AS final_exam_level...` This would match an Exam_id to the count of exam_id's. You might want to clarify why you couldn't use the joins

Comment: I tried doing your SQL but, I will have to change the JOIN IN and because you also used JOIN IN to count the exam_IDs I didnt really know how to change it

Comment: I dont think you can name a subquery in Access

Comment: No you can. Here's a trivial example you can test with `SELECT foo.* , bar.* FROM 
(SELECT count(*)
FROM MSysObjects ) foo , (SELECT max(name)
FROM MSysObjects ) bar`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing without seeing example data but maybe try this, change

```
AND (Student.S_ID)=Exam_Allocation.S_ID
AND ((Exams.Exam_ID)=Exam_Allocation.Exam_ID)
```

to

```
AND Student.S_ID=Exams.Exam_ID
AND Exams.Exam_ID=Exam_Allocation.Exam_ID
```

If this does not help you will need to post some example data with expected and actual results for someone to help.

Comment: It doesnt help, I think all the joins are correct. Any other suggestions.